# How to search a string of characters for a string of letters inputted from the user using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, textbox

How do I get the number of times the a value occurs in a string?

Say I have 2 textboxes.

One lets the user enter, let's say, up to 5 characters, the other textbox lets the user enter any string, at any length.

What code would you use to find how many times the input from the first textbox occurs in the input of the second in javascript?

Comment: Show us some code! I suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking!

Comment: function checkLength()
 {
 var tbx1 = document.getElementById("one").value;
 var str = document.getElementById("search").value;
 
 var n = tbx1.search();
 alert(n);
 }

Comment: Thats what I have and if you don't want to help it's alright but can't get this working?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some simple code

```
var pattern = $("#sometextbox1").val();
var text = $("#sometextbox2").val();
var count = 1;
while(text.indexOf(patter)!==-1){
    $text = $text.replace(pattern, "");
    count++;
}
```

count is the number of appearance